# Strange behavior when checking %{REQUEST_FILENAME} in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm confusing with my htaccess configuration. This is my site's structure:

```
\www
    \public
        \css
        \js
```

In `www` directory, I have a htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.example\.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [NC,L]
```

And this one is in `public` directory:

```
RewriteBase /public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [NC,L]
```

When I access `css` directory, browser address bar will shows in 2 different ways:

www.example.com/css    ->  www.example.com/public/css/

www.example.com/css/   ->  www.example.com/css/

Anyone can explain to me this difference and how can I configure to make both of them will return the second result `www.example.com/css/`

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to `mod_dir` adding a trailing slash after your rewrite rules. Have your root .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/ !-d [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work. I have solved my problem by create a virtualhost to my public folder.

Comment: This is tested and working  rule on my web server. If your problem is solved, then you can delete this question.